# Page is not found while downloading the file in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

i am working on code for pdf download that same pdf file would be downloaded every time when user click the download but when i click on download i get page not found error.
as well as browser showing the path that is not the actual path of that file..my file path is /home/ujjwal/project/media.

here is my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL=' /media/'
```

and urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
     urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

html file:

```
<a href="/media/bhagwati_invoice.pdf">
<button class="btn" style="width:100%"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</button></a>
```

and getting following error

Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/media/bhagwati_invoice.pdf

Comment: The gap in the `' /media/'` string is only a typing error ? Or it is the direct copy of your source code ?

Comment: Thanks man you saved me..now working good...i was frustrated since morning. Thanks a-lot.